# Do compound shard keys in MongoDB work similar to compound indexes?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose my collection uses a compound shard key consisting of BlockHash and BlockHeight fields.

If I ran a query to look up documents for a given BLockHeight, will Mongo have to hit every shard since we did not filter by BlockHash? Does having BlockHeight in the shard key help the query at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally every query should have the shard key. Choose based on cardinality and logical categorisation of your data.

If you are sharding on BlockHash and BlockHeight (in that order), and you just run a query on BlockHeight. You will end up with hitting all the shards.

As a best practice, make it a habit of running .explain("executionStats") with your queries. This will tell you how your query is parsed. And which Shards did it touch.

Comment: Even worse, if there is no index that starts from "BLockHeight" it will be a collection scan on all shards.

Comment: You can't do shard without index

Comment: Thank you for the info both of you!